# pipe() data to Json file or to PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

i have this code:

```
var MetaUtil = require('osm-meta-util');
var meta = MetaUtil({
                      'delay': 1000,
                      'start': '000598424', //file number
                      'end': '001122000' //file number
                   }).pipe(process.stdout) //outputs to console
```

How can i pipe the output to Json file so i can later upload it into Postgresql Database.

With Regards

Andrey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file writable stream and pipe data into it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./output.json')
MetaUtil({
    'delay': 1000,
    'start': '000598424', //file number
    'end': '001122000' //file number
}).pipe(file);
```

And in reverse, use a readable stream to read the data from the file and insert it into the database according to the database framework that you are using.

I'm not familiar with postres but [`pg-copy-streams`](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams#pipe-from-a-file-to-table) seems to be what provides this functionality for it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pg = require('pg');
var copyFrom = require('pg-copy-streams').from;

pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  var stream = client.query(copyFrom('COPY my_table FROM STDIN'));
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('some_file.tsv')
  fileStream.on('error', done);
  fileStream.pipe(stream).on('finish', done).on('error', done);
});
```

Comment: thank u very much. is working . can u give me some link to a tutorials that teach how to manipulate In/output flow?